# It it possible to add a foreign key constraint to a composite key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have 2 tables.

subject_schedule:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject_schedule` (
  `subject` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `schedule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject`,`schedule_id`),
  KEY `schedule_id` (`schedule_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and appointment:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointment` (
  `work_plan` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `homework_given` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tutor_comments` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_comments` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedule_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attended` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `arrival_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `homework_completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subject` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `schedule_id` (`schedule_id`),
  KEY `subject` (`subject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10004 ;
```

I want to create a foreign key which references the composite key in appointment. I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE 'appointment'
ADD CONSTRAINT 'appointment_fk' FOREIGN KEY (`schedule_id`, `subject`) 
REFERENCES 'subject_schedule' ('schedule_id', 'subject');
```

but it returns an error in PhpMyAdmin:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''appointment' ADD CONSTRAINT 'appointment_fk' FOREIGN KEY
>   (`schedule_id`, `su' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?
Is it better to just have an id as a primary key and reference that instead of using a composite key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the columnNames shouldn't be wrap with single quotes because it will be converted to a string (*not a column anymore*)

```
ALTER TABLE appointment
ADD CONSTRAINT appointment_fk FOREIGN KEY (`schedule_id`, `subject`) 
REFERENCES subject_schedule (schedule_id, subject);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95f8a/1)

Comment: @user1975196 click the sql fiddle link

Comment: Thankyou it worked! I just had to update some of my records to comply with the constraints.

Comment: Another question. Do I need the:
  KEY `schedule_id` (`schedule_id`),
  KEY `subject` (`subject`)

in the create table then?

Comment: before i'll answer your question, let me ask this first, how are the two tabkles related with each other? by that I mean what are their linking columns?

Comment: oh yes, i get it. No, you don;t need that. the alter statement which add foreign key constraint automatically adds an index for you.